# Pandas: How to search a column for a set of strings?

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame containing a column with tweets. These text contains the so called '@' mentions. I want to add a new column to this data frame containing the particular '@' mention that was found in that row. Code:

```
dfEx5.text.apply(str) #Convert all elements in the text-column to a string-type

dfEx5['mentions'] = pd.np.where(dfEx5.text.str.contains("@AmericanAir"), "@AmericanAir",
                    pd.np.where(dfEx5.text.str.contains("@JetBlue"), "@JetBlue",
                    pd.np.where(dfEx5.text.str.contains("@SouthwestAir"), "@SouthwestAir",
                    pd.np.where(dfEx5.text.str.contains("@united"), "@united",
                    pd.np.where(dfEx5.text.str.contains("@USAirways"), "@USAirways",
                    pd.np.where(dfEx5.text.str.contains("@VirginAmerica"), "@VirginAmerica",))))))
```

First I converted all elements to a string-type. If the column contains '@AmericanAir' then put '@AmericanAir' in the mention column, etc.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `dfEx5.str.extract(r'(@AmericanAir|@JetBlue....')` etc.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there's more than one mention?

Comment: @Jon Clements I am assuming that each tweet is about one company. But you are right, if there is more than one company mentioned in the tweet, I would want to use the one that was mentioned first.

Answer (score 0):

#### `pandas.Series.str.findall`

I'd find all mentions within my watch group and take first one.

```
df.text.str.findall('|'.join(watch)).str[0]

0      @AmericanAir
1          @JetBlue
2     @SouthwestAir
3           @united
4        @USAirways
5    @VirginAmerica
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Add it to a new column via `assign`

```
df.assign(mentions=df.text.str.findall('|'.join(watch)).str[0])

                    text        mentions
0  @AmericanAir @JetBlue    @AmericanAir
1               @JetBlue        @JetBlue
2          @SouthwestAir   @SouthwestAir
3  @united @SouthwestAir         @united
4             @USAirways      @USAirways
5         @VirginAmerica  @VirginAmerica
```

You can leave all mentions if you'd like

```
df.assign(mentions=df.text.str.findall('|'.join(watch)))

                    text                  mentions
0  @AmericanAir @JetBlue  [@AmericanAir, @JetBlue]
1               @JetBlue                [@JetBlue]
2          @SouthwestAir           [@SouthwestAir]
3  @united @SouthwestAir  [@united, @SouthwestAir]
4             @USAirways              [@USAirways]
5         @VirginAmerica          [@VirginAmerica]
```

---

#### Setup

```
watch = [
    '@SouthwestAir',
    '@VirginAmerica',
    '@united',
    '@JetBlue',
    '@USAirways',
    '@AmericanAir'
]
text = """\
@AmericanAir @JetBlue
@JetBlue
@SouthwestAir
@united @SouthwestAir
@USAirways
@VirginAmerica
"""
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(text=text.splitlines()))

df

                    text
0  @AmericanAir @JetBlue
1               @JetBlue
2          @SouthwestAir
3  @united @SouthwestAir
4             @USAirways
5         @VirginAmerica
```

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to work yet. How is the column 'text' of 'dfEx5' searched for mentions of one of the six companies? And how is that name printed in the 'mention' column? Thanks!

Comment: I can't help you unless you post a concrete example.  Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.